# Visual Studio: Where is IntelliSense in the Immediate Window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

It would seem the Immediate window needs some jazzing up ala IntelliSense?

Anyone agree/disagree? Is this coming in VS2008/2010?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ctrl + Space in immediate if you don't have the intellisense coming up automatically. Like Joel, intellisense seems to come in go in the immed window.

Comment: when it's gone, ctrl+space doesn't seem to help much :(

Comment: In general, I found that Intellisense works in Debug mode, but not in a "non-debug" mode. (A little known fact is that the Immediate window is still usable and functions even when not in debug mode.) But, I agree with Joel it is inconsistent.

Comment: It used to work for me, but recently, even in debug mode, it doesn't. Ctrl + space does not help.

Comment: It is a known issue caused by Resharper installation. Ctrl+Space should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

When debugging in Visual Studio 2008, you can get intellisense to pop up by pressing ctrl+space.  Also, it will pop up in a quick watch window with the same keystroke.  Very handy.

Answer (score 3):

I am in VS2005 with C#, I finally get it up with Ctrl-Space but oddly i have to try it a few times when i first click in there.  It will work fine for a while as long as I stay in that window.

But If i click into the problems or the find window, and back to it: then it doesn't really come up again until I evaluate one line and THEN hit Ctrl-Space.