# Visual studio Debugger Copy object

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2012, moq

I am wondering if anything like this exists:

When debugging in visual studio it would be really good if it had the ability to copy an object(all its properties and values) into memory. I am thinking of something that you could put a break point in code -> right click the object -> Click "create moq into clipboard"

Then you could go to your unit test, paste the text which would paste the code to create that object with all of those properties.

I imagine this would save loads of time, and would be really useful for fixing bugs.

One of the difficult things I find with unit test is the manual process in creating the mock objects.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927991/copy-object-values-in-visual-studio-debug-mode

Answer (score 11):

I'm a bit late to the party but I created a Visual Studio extension that does something very similar to what you're looking for. It will generate C# code to initialize an object from your visual studio debugging windows.

Here's the extension: [**Visual Studio Marketplace > Object Explorer**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter)

And here's an accompanying blog post: [**Exporting Objects from the Visual Studio Debugger**](https://www.omarelabd.net/exporting-objects-from-the-visual-studio-debugger/)

Comment: That extension unfortunately doesn't support VS2022. This is something similar that does work with VS2022: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YevhenCherkes.YellowFlavorObjectDumper

Answer (score -1):

If you find it onerous to create mock objects, there is likely a problem with your design or the way your using mock objects.  You shouldn't create mocks for simple 'value' objects - just use the actual objects in your unit tests.  For more complex objects that your object-under-test interacts with, the interactions should be few, otherwise you may have excessive coupling between objects.  As a rule of thumb, if it's hard to test, the design is probably wrong.

Comment: I think this statement is true for a green fields project. However I am working in an existing system that does not have much in the way of unit tests, and I dont have much time to refactor at present. Problem solving areas within the system means stepping through a lot of stuff which is time consuming. I would be thinking of using this as a debug tool, which could save time and help the transition into a system with more unit tests.

Comment: OK, working with legacy code is a different situation!  Short answer: I'm not aware of anything to generate mock code from within the debugger.  Long answer: Michael Feathers' Working Effectively With Legacy Code has good advice on other ways to deal with testing legacy code. http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052