# Visual Studio or Visual Code extension that generate C# object or List<object>

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have to create test cases by creating dummy object for the many classes. for example Employee unit test class, I have to create Department, Address, Job etc., Is there a VS code or Visual studio which can generate all these object when I select or choose employee and choose generate object.

like the one in this link, its no more available.
https://executecommands.com/top-7-must-have-visual-studio-2019-extensions/#4-object-exporter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy object values in Visual Studio debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927991/copy-object-values-in-visual-studio-debug-mode)

Comment: NuGet package, [ObjectDumper.NET](https://github.com/thomasgalliker/ObjectDumper). Although it might seem less convenient than an an extension, it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

[Object Dumper](https://github.com/ycherkes/ObjectDumper) is a [FOSS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) extension for both [Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YevhenCherkes.YellowFlavorObjectDumper) and [Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YevhenCherkes.object-dumper).

It's exporting objects to **C#**, **JSON**, **Visual Basic**, **XML**, and **YAML**.