# Simulating a missing object while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I was just searching for debugging options in visual studio debugger where I can simulate missing object conditions ie., (this.XX == null). I wanted to know is there any way i can assign a null value to the field "XX" in debug session? What i wanted exactly is equivalent to de-allocating the memory assigned to entire XX field (the XX internally contains several other data structures).

All my search results tells me how to edit but i would like to know how to de-allocate? Does MSVC has any such options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint you should be able to hover over the `this.XX` property which will bring up its current value, you can then click into the value and replace it with `null`.

Alternatively you could use a conditional statement in your code like so

```
#if DEBUG
    this.XX = null;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Immediate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794255/how-do-you-use-the-immediate-window-in-visual-studio), also.

You can type some statements inside it, and add some code while the code is paused in a breakpoint.