# writing text to response not working when exception is thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to write some text before the line is throwing the exception, I want to view that text written by response, anyway I cannot see that, but only the exception is shown, Where can I find that text now.. The code below may give a clear picture.

```
res.Write(col1);
res.Write(colms);
String colName = colms[col1];
```

Now i am getting this exception at the third line:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

I want to see those values as shown in code, but that is not working. In Java I used to do something like

```
System.out.println(col1);
```

and that will print to the netbeans console. Now i am using VS2010. How to achieve that same here?

Comment: Do you want to avoid exception or print in console?

Comment: i want to print those values in console, before the exception occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Debug.Print`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9azyssyh.aspx) to print to an attached debug listener (presumably VS):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(col1.ToString());
```

Comment: will this print to console, that is a generic handler.

Comment: @user2003821 If you mean the console in Visual Studio (Output window, show output from Debug), yes.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about the following error

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

Problem can be

```
 String colName = colms[col1];
```

Index out of range means you are trying to access an index which is not in the range.

### Edit 1

You can put break point to see what values are coming in your variable.

Here is good link about break points
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/21/vs-2010-debugger-improvements-breakpoints-datatips-import-export.aspx

### Edit 2

You can also take benefit of immediate window.

[How do you use the Immediate Window in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794255/how-do-you-use-the-immediate-window-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I know that problem but i asked for diffrent solution, I think first answer is somewhat related, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in try block, you will be able to access col1 in the catch block.