# C# Is it possible to testing if statement using immediate window in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i want to test `if` statements directly, my problem is it's waiting so many long to test my `if` statements in my `code`. this is my `code` :

```
    byte isFive = _checkReadLengthIsFive;

    if (readLength == 5)
    {
        isFive++;
        _checkReadLengthIsFive = isFive;
        if (isFive == 2)
        {
           string appendText = "WRITE FAIL" + Environment.NewLine;
           File.AppendAllText(Fullpath, appendText);
           DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "DAPAT!" + "\n");
        }
    }
```

to reach in this `if` statement, i waiting so long because `readLength = 5` is rarely happening. Is it possible to use immediate window? if possible please tell me how? thanks for helping and responses.

Comment: did you use breakpoint?

Comment: Short ans: No, immediate window only can help you execute code without variables (i.e. 5==6).  You may find more information in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1361136/1050927.

Comment: Unit Tests are useful for this, you can setup your test so that you can test edge cases

Comment: why the downvote??

Comment: 1) use breakpoints to stop at the desired line of code before it is evaluated. 2) use watches for monitoring variables. 3) If you wanna get or set the values of scope variables then use the immediate window.

Comment: yes i use breakpoint. i confuse in immediate window

Comment: how to test if statement directly in immediate window? is it possible?

Comment: If you use breakpoint as suggested, you don't need to test in immediate window.

Comment: i use breakpoint but i still wait so long because the if statement is rarely happen and breakpoint not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test your code inside if statement, just change the code from

> if (readLength == 5)

to

> if (true)

After everything is ok, you change back to if (readLength == 5)

Comment: change in immediate window or where ?

Comment: I think no need to use immediate window. As you say you need to wait so long to make the if statement happens, my idea is why don't modify the code to make the if statement happen, then test the code inside if statement.

Comment: oh so if we want to test the code only with if(true)

Comment: why be like that? sorry i am really new in c# . could you explain it more detail?

Comment: AS I understand, you want to test if statements directly, and your problem is it's waiting so many long to test your if statements in your code, so change the code to if (true) so that it can always happen then you no need to wait so long to test your code.

Comment: this is already i try and this is what i need! big thanks for you. @Huu Thien Tan Nguyen

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change a variable's value in the immediate window while your code is running (debugging). You should be able to set the variable's value by using the window and typing something like readLength = 5;. You are also able to hover the mouse over the variable and click on the value and type in a new value.

Comment: what must i type in immediate window? i see only blank sir

Comment: Watch window too.

Comment: By the way, the immediate window and watch window are only useful when your program has hit a breakpoint. Put a breakpoint on your line 'if(readLength == 5), when that breakpoint is hit type 'readLength = 6' into the immediate window. Here is a short but handy tutorial on the immediate window to get you started:  http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSImmediate.aspx

Comment: this if is rarely happen sir, when we waiting breakpoint hit if(readLength==5), it's waste time too long because that if rarely happens