# Error CS0103: The Name 'NNN' Does Not Exist In The Current Context

Tags: c#, visual-studio

VS2017 - not the first time I have seen this kind of insanity.  As you can see, intellisense in the immediate window seems to know all about this variable, yet I'm about to be told it doesn't exist.  Hovering the name in the code in debug doesn't offer the typical, friendly aid to display the object members there, either.  I can use the 'count' property to set a variable in code, but I can't print that same property in the immediate window.  Other strange things were happening, too - step over (F10) would sometimes skip statements.  Tried restarting VS, but not rebooting the computer.  Clean solution - no help.  It's a class library using iTextSharp that is referenced into a WinForms project and breakpoint at the instance shown in the image is in the class library, if any of that matters.

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using SD = System.Drawing;
using iTextSharp;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

[image: Immediate window madness]

Comment: Delete the bin and obj folders, this sounds as if an old version of the binary is still cached (sometimes Clean Solution doesn't clear everything)

Comment: @Erno Sorry, that's not it, but thanks.

Comment: In the immediate window, we cannot call function directly. Please use this format to call your function: `? new sdSplitTiffs().Add();`. More details: [C# code for immediate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794255/how-do-you-use-the-immediate-window-in-visual-studio/1361136#1361136).

Comment: The member I'm trying to use in the immediate window is the Count property, not the Add function.