# VBA Access If statement doesn't contain a certain character

Tags: vba, ms-access, if-statement, ms-access-2010

I am trying to write in Access an If statement that changes the value of a form value depending on the fact that another value doesn't contain the character "*".

So far, I have this :

```
If Forms![Saisie commande panier]![Qualité].Value = "CA" _
Or Forms![Saisie commande panier]![Qualité].Value = "Salarié" _
And Not Forms![Saisie commande panier]![SF_Panier]![SF_Détail_panier]![Designation].contains "*" Then
Forms![Saisie commande panier]![SF_Panier]![SF_Détail_panier]![Remise] = "30"
```

Which, of course, is not working.
Do you have any solution for that ?

Knowing that this form is a spreadsheet. NOT LIKE doesn't work, <> doesn't work either... There must be a simple function, right ?

Thank you for your help,
Flo

Comment: It is `InStr` that searches a text value.

Comment: ` If Forms![Saisie commande panier]![Qualité].Value = "CA" _
Or Forms![Saisie commande panier]![Qualité].Value = "Salarié" _
And InStr(Forms![Saisie commande panier]![SF_Panier]![SF_Détail_panier]![Designation], "*") = False Then
Forms![Saisie commande panier]![SF_Panier]![SF_Détail_panier]![Remise] = "30"

End If `                                             **Says the type is not compatible. Also tried with**                                              
 ` AND Not  InStr(Forms![Saisie commande panier]![SF_Panier]![SF_Détail_panier]![Designation], "*")  Then `

Answer (score 3):

Use [Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator): `If Not someControl Like "*[*]*" Then`
Note that the `not` is before the expression in VBA, while in SQL you could use `not like`.

Regarding your comment, I suspect the problem is in `Forms![Saisie commande panier]![SF_Panier]![SF_Détail_panier]![Designation]`. You probably miss a `Form` somewhere.  See [this one](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) or [this one](http://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/primer/index.html).
It's probably something like
`Forms![Saisie commande panier]![SF_Panier].Form![SF_Détail_panier].Form![Designation]`
By the way, **if** your code is in the main form, you could write it
`Me![SF_Panier].Form![SF_Détail_panier].Form![Designation]`

Comment: `If Forms![Saisie commande panier]![Qualité].Value = "CA" _
Or Forms![Saisie commande panier]![Qualité].Value = "Salarié" _
And Not Forms![Saisie commande panier]![SF_Panier]![SF_Détail_panier]![Designation] Like "*[*]*" Then
Forms![Saisie commande panier]![SF_Panier]![SF_Détail_panier]![Remise] = "30"

End If`    It says that the type is not compatible :(

Comment: Error might be somewhere else, like in `Remise = 30` (no quotes)

Comment: No it stops at the line before, right on "And not Form!... Like... "

Comment: @FlorenceS see updated answer. Is your code in form [Saisie commande panier] ?

Comment: Following what you said `If Forms![Saisie commande panier]![Qualité].Value = "CA" _
Or Forms![Saisie commande panier]![Qualité].Value = "Salarié" _
And Not Me![SF_Détail_panier].Form.[Designation] Like "*[*]*" Then
Me![SF_Détail_panier].Form.[Remise] = "30"

End If`    Still not working. Knowing my button is on [SF_Panier] (really useful link however, thx)

Comment: If you use your immediate window, you can evaluate each component of your IF statement separately to find exactly which part is causing the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794255/how-do-you-use-the-immediate-window-in-visual-studio E.g. `?Not Forms![Saisie commande panier]![SF_Panier]![SF_Détail_panier]![Designation] Like "*[*]*"`

Comment: Well, no more error, but nothing happens. I tried with Not like... and InStr. I think I'm just not gonna do it...

Comment: C'est en forgeant qu'on devient fort en jurons 8-)